# Why is Oracle Apex generating an error "Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated update error"

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an interactive report which is launching an update form.  When I am saving the record in the form I keep getting this error message.

> Current version of data in database has changed since user initiated
>   update process. current row version identifier =
>   "cZn-64OiKHJCbgxCjZOU0LN1zfM" application row version identifier =
>   "bXTD5weQFc5M3rkpx_XBv_qKN7s"

This is despite the fact that I am the only person in the database, so this can't be optimistic locking.

I am using Apex 5.

Comment: Ah...I notice I have a dynamic action linked to the button which ends with a Submit step. But in my button I am not choosing the action "Defined by Dynamic Action", I am using a "Submit" action.  So I guess my button is submitting and my dynamic action is submitting again?  Can that happen?

Comment: A page can only be submitted once.  But if the dynamic action is changing data and submitting the page is changing data then whichever one comes second would find that the data had changed.

Comment: OK, seems to have fixed it now, doing submit only as end of dynamic action.  Thanks.